# How to display the buttons in each card based on the condition (0/1) in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS. I have 2 cards, with 2 buttons each `On` and `OFF`.

One card should display `On` button and the other should display `OFF` button based on the condition.

If `Value =1` then the card should display only `ON` button not the `OFF` button and If `Value = 0` then the card should display `Off` button.

But, both the cards should not display `ON` and `Off` in both of them. There should not any event like `Click`.

While loading the page, One card should display `On` button and the other card should display `Off`. *But not the both.*

Here is the code:

```js
var condition = 0;

if(condition == 0){
  $('.on').hide();
  $('.off').show();
}
else {
  $('.off').hide();
  $('.on').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
             Card 1 
            </div>
      </div>
     <div class ="card-body">
          <button class ="on"> ON </button>
          <button class ="off"> OFF </button>
     </div>
</div>
<!--card 2-->
<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
             Card 1 
            </div>
      </div>
     <div class ="card-body">
          <button class ="on"> ON </button>
          <button class ="off"> OFF </button>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-title">
             Card 2 
            </div>
      </div>
     <div class ="card-body">
          <button class ="on"> ON </button>
          <button class ="off"> OFF </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

But, I could not get both the cards with Either `On` or `OFF`. Both the card displays `Off` button. I need one card with `On` and one with `off`.

How could I write a condition to show Either `On/Off`. I don't want to use `toggle`.

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: i image this condition is not hardcoded, where that come?

Comment: If you want to one card ON and other card OFF then what is role of value=0 or value=1?

Comment: Please use the snippet tool `<>` when you edit the question and create a reproducible view of the problem

Comment: @JigneshsinhRathod , I need Value = 0 for one card and Value =1 for the other card. How could I do that? Could you please help?

Comment: @Dar You mean when Value=0 then first card shows OFF button then what second card will show, i don`t get your problem properly so please explain me in detail, i will help you.

Comment: @JigneshsinhRathod, I need to display both the cards simulataneously when the page loads. Each card has 2 buttons in them `ON` and `Off`. But, both of the cards should never display both `on` and `off` together. One  card should display `On`and the other card should display `Off`based on the condition(0/1). How could write a code for the  condition for the cards to display either `On` or `OFF`. The problem is , when I used  the above JS code, I could get `ON` in both the cards. I need one card with `On` and the other with `OFF`. Could you please help me? Many thanks.

Comment: @Dar Just tell me when condition = 0 then what will happens on both card and condition = 1 then what will happend with both card. You mean when card 1 is ON then card 2 is OFF and card 1 is OFF then card 2 is ON, is it?

Comment: @JigneshsinhRathod, Yes, When card1  is ON, card 2 should be OFF, and Vice Versa. Is it possible to create a condition: 0 for card 1 and conidtion : 1 for card 2? Thank you